# Push Array in same array results in circular reference

Tags: javascript, arrays, circular-reference

I am trying to push the same array in array.Why is it creating the circular reference?

```
var arr =[4,4];
arr.push(arr);
console.log(arr)
// Expected output = [4,4,[4,4]]
// actual output = [4,4,[4,4,[4,4,[...]]]
```

Comment: Because...you push *literally the same array* inside itself.

Comment: The array gets pushed as a pointer. Printing then goes over all of the elements and follows all pointers. This can never terminate.

Comment: please add the wanted result as well. do you want to keep the reference to `arr`?

Comment: I just want to know the reason behind circular reference in this case.  @NinaScholz

Comment: @komalbansal see my answer for reason.

Comment: @PradyumanDixit I already know that the array is pushed just once and creating a circular reference.My question is simply why is it so, when it should push the value of z which is [4,4] at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Because the first element is the array, the first element of the element is a reference to the outer array, and so on.

You're looking for `Array#slice`:

```js
const arr1 = [4, 4]
arr1.push (arr1.slice (0)) // <-- slice creates a new array
                         //     whose members are the same as
                         //     arr1

console.log (arr1)
```

*Spread syntax*  can also assist on this issue:

```js
const arr1 = [4, 4]
arr1.push ([...arr1]) // spread syntax
console.log (arr1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing the same array. One option is, you can use the `spread syntax` to iterable each array element and construct a new one.

Like:

```js
var arr = [4, 4];
arr.push([...arr]);
console.log(arr)
```

Doc: [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)